# Efficient functor dispatcher

Tags: c++, templates, dispatcher

I need help understanding two different versions of functor dispatcher, see here:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
double* psi;
double dx = 0.1;
int range;
struct A
{
    double operator()(int x) const
    {
        return dx* (double)x*x;
    }
};

template <typename T>
void dispatchA()
{
    constexpr T op{};

    for (int i=0; i<range; i++)
        psi[i]+=op.operator()(i);
}

template <typename T>
void dispatchB(T op)
{

    for (int i=0; i<range; i++)
        psi[i]+=op.operator()(i);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    range= argc;
    psi = new double[range];
    dispatchA<A>();
    // dispatchB<A>(A{});
}
```

Live at https://godbolt.org/z/93h5T46oq

The dispatcher will be called many times in a big loop, so I need to make sure that I'm doing it right.
Both version seem to me unnecessarily complex since the type of the functor is known at compile-time.
DispatchA, because it unnecessarily creates an (constexpr) object.
DispatchB, because it passes the object over and over.

Of course those could be solved by a) making the a static function in the functor,
but static functions are bad practice, right?
b) making a static instance of the functor inside the dispatcher, but then the lifetime of the object grows to the lifetime of the program.

That being said I don't know enough assembly to meaningfully compare the two appoaches.
Is there a more elegant/efficient approach?

Comment: Add compiler optimization settings to your live demos.  And then you need to measure inspecting the generated assembly can be counter intuitive on todays out-of-order, pre-fetching, multi-instruction CPUs.  The last time counting instructions / clock cycles was possible was the 80186.

Comment: `A` is currently stateless, so `dispatchB` is 0 overhead.

Comment: Also `op.operator()(i)` is a silly way to write `op(i)`

Comment: If `dispatchB` took the parameter by reference, it'd be optimal even if A was stateful, I think

Comment: @RichardCritten right, forgot to enable them - but it's still not clear to me which one is the winner.

Comment: If `A` is stateless, `static double operator()(int x) const` is marginally more efficient.

Comment: @MooingDuck thanks, right.

Comment: @Ranza that's because these days it is impossible to tell without measuring.  Speculative, out-of-order, pre-fetching, etc means that code inspection for performance is mostly pointless.  Designing a proper benchmark (making sure you are testing what you mean to test) and measuring is the only way forward.

Comment: @PaulSanders operator() can't be static, and static can't be const - you mean a seperate function like: A::calc()?

Comment: Oh, OK, my bad.  Yes then, the point being that calling a `static` function is marginally cheaper than calling a non-static one since no `this` pointer has to be passed,

Comment: @RichardCritten and what about a third, easier way?

Comment: @Ranza These guys can't find a way without measuring - CppCon Performance - https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=cppcon+performance

Comment: As has been said already, you generally can't inspect the assembly to determine performance; you should use something like [quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com) or a benchmarking library. That said, if you actually enable optimizations, the two produce **identical assembly** due to inlining ([check the comparison](https://godbolt.org/z/655TvoarY)), which means either approach should yield similar characteristics

Comment: @Human-Compiler Looks like the difference is less than the margin of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely isn't the answer you are looking for, but the general advice you are going to get from almost any seasoned developer is to just write the code in a natural/understandable way, and only optimize if you need to.

This may sound like a non-answer, but it's actually good advice.

The majority of the time, the cost you *may* (if at all) incur due to small decisions like this will be inconsequential overall. Generally, you'll see more gains when optimizing *an algorithm* more so than optimizing a *few instructions*. There are, indeed, exceptions to this rule -- but generally such optimizations are part of a *tight loop* -- and this is the type of thing you can retroactively look at by profiling and benchmarking.

It's better to write code in a way that can be maintained in the future, and only really optimizing it if this proves to be an issue down the line.

---

For the code in question, both code-snippets when optimized produce [identical assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/655TvoarY) -- meaning that both approach *should* perform equally as well in practice (provided the calling characteristics are the same). But even then, [benchmarking](https://quick-bench.com) would be the only real way to verify this.

Since the dispatchers are function `template` definitions, they are implicitly `inline`, and their definition will always be visible before invoking. Often, this is enough for an optimizer to both introspect and inline such code (if it deems this is better than not).

> ... static functions are bad practice, right?

No; `static` functions are not bad practice. Like any utility in C++, they can surely be misused -- but there is nothing inherently bad about them.

> DispatchA, ... unnecessarily creates an (constexpr) object

`constexpr` objects are constructed at compile-time -- and so you would not see any real cost to this other than perhaps a bit more space on the stack being reserved. This cost would really be minimal.

You could also make this `static constexpr` instead if you really wanted to avoid this. Although logically the "lifetime of the object grows to the lifetime of the program" as you mentioned, `constexpr` objects cannot have exit-time behavior in C++, so the cost is virtually nonexistent.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `A` is stateless, as it is in your example, and has no non-static data members, they are identical. The compiler is smart enough to see that construction of the object is a no-op and omits it. Let's clear up your code a bit to get clean assembly we can easily reason about:

```
struct A {
  double operator()(int) const noexcept;
};

void useDouble(double);
int genInt();

void dispatchA() {
  constexpr A op{};
  auto const range = genInt();
  for (int i = 0; i < range; i++) useDouble(op(genInt()));
}

void dispatchB(A op) {
  auto const range = genInt();
  for (int i = 0; i < range; i++) useDouble(op(genInt()));
}
```

Here, where input comes from and where the output goes is abstracted away. Generated assembly can only differ because of how the `op` object is created. Compiling it with GCC 11.1, I get [identical assembly generation](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9a89nMnsW). No creation or initialization of `A` takes place.

Comment: Thanks, for calming me down :-)